# How to bind a dictionary to MSChart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I am trying to bind Dictionary to a Chart, 
Below is the code

```
    IDictionary<double, double> dict1 = new Dictionary<double, double>();
    IList<double> list1 = new List<double>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitialiseDictionary();

        Series ser1 = new Series("My Series", 10);
        chart1.Series.Add(ser1);
        chart1.DataSource = dict1;
        chart1.DataBind();
    }

    private void InitialiseDictionary()
    {
        for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < 1000;i = i + 100 , j=j+10)
            dict1.Add(i , j);
    }
```

But I don't see the Chart or graph on winform.
am I missing anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution,
the constructor Form1() is modified as below

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitialiseDictionary();
    Series ser1 = new Series("My Series", 10);
    chart1.Series.Add(ser1);
    chart1.Series["My Series"].Points.DataBindXY(dict1.Keys, dict1.Values);
}
```