# drawing a graph in WinForms with dictionary dataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, charts

I want to draw a graph in WinForms which is built out of **Attribute List** this should become a **Series**, for every attribute in the list it has to display its **parameters** **with the name** and the **value** or appropriateness that this attribute has with this specific parameter which is the key in my Dictyonary From class Attributes.

```
  private void Graph_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var attribute in Attribute.listAttributes)
            {
                Series s = new Series();
                s.Name = attribute.name;
                chart.Series.Add(attribute.name);


                foreach (var parameter in attribute.appropriatenessList)
                {
                    chart.DataSource = parameter;
                    chart.Series[attribute.name].XValueMember = parameter.Key.name;
                    chart.Series[attribute.name].YValuesPerPoint = parameter.Value;

                }

            }

            chart.DataBind();

        }
```

This is my first time making a chart and I don't get any feedback from the program because, every time I run the code the chart comes back empty!

link to the example of a chart that I need to make:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfS6E.png

how should I fix this code ??

Comment: What happens when you step through the code with the debugger?

Comment: I have double-checked with debugger and I don't see anything that would bother me. the value of key.name is being set properly for XValueMember (string) and the same goes for YValue (int) ....... "I think".

Comment: You are ignoring your Series, but anyway, try it this way: [How to bind a dictionary to MSChart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135087/719186)

Comment: I did try to make this work before but the key is typeof Parameter and dataBindXY only works with int, double ...

Comment: You probably have to give us a bit more information to recreate the chart on our end.  Some sample data.  What the chart is supposed to look like, etc.

Comment: BTW, `chart.DataSource = parameter;` is only setting the DataSource for the *last* parameter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I forgot to mention ListOfAttributes represent all the objects they were created so it is **static** the class also contains Dictionary <Parameter,int> appropriateness that represents some value for the **specific** Attribute. Here is an example of a chart  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfS6E.png) .